# Problema para usar o return (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou começando agora e tentei fazer de acordo com a explicação do meu professor, mas não estou conseguindo rodar a função. Quero que retorne para o começo se o usuário responder errado ao invés de apenas encerrar.

```
def paintcalculator():
    print("What measurement unit do you use?")
    unit = int(input("What measurement unit do you use?\n1 - Meters \n2 - Centimeters \n3 - Inches \nOption number:"))
    
    if unit == 1:  #meters
        height = float(input('What is the  height of the wall? '))
        width = float(input('What is the width of the wall? '))
        layers = float(input('How many layers do you want to use? '))
        area = height * width
        liters = 2 * area * layers
        print('You will need aproximately {:.2f} liters of paint.'.format(liters)) 

    elif unit == 2:  #centimeters
        height = float(input('What is the  height of the wall? '))
        width = float(input('What is the width of the wall? '))
        layers = float(input('How many layers do you want to use? '))
        area = (height*0.01) * (width*0.01)
        liters = 2 * area * layers
        print('You will need aproximately {:.2f} liters of paint.'.format(liters)) 

    elif unit == 3:  #inches
        height = float(input('What is the  height of the wall? '))
        width = float(input('What is the width of the wall? '))
        layers = float(input('How many layers do you want to use? '))
        area = (height*0.0254) * (width*0.0254)
        liters = 2 * area * layers
        print('You will need aproximately {:.2f} liters of paint.'.format(liters)) 

    else:
        print('Please, answer correctly.')
        return paintcalculator()
```

Comment: Ao contrário do que a resposta abaixo sugeriu, chamar a função `paintcalculator` dentro dela mesma não é a melhor opção, pois isso é um uso indevido de [recursão](/q/21551/112052) e isso pode causar problemas (além de ser uma complicação desnecessária). O melhor é usar um *loop* (como o `while` por exemplo). Como não ficou claro pra mim quando é para sair e quando é pra continuar, segue uma sugestão/palpite: https://ideone.com/bBFNp0

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde

Bom pelo que eu não acho tão legal chamar a função dentro dela mesmo, no caso de sua aplicação criar uma estrutura de repetição infinita como whle True: já estaria funcionando, assim bastaria criar uma opção para encerrar o menu

segue a alteração feita:

```
def paintcalculator():

while True:
    print("What measurement unit do you use?")
    unit = int(input("What measurement unit do you use?\n1 - Meters \n2 - Centimeters \n3 - Inches \nIf you want break this program press number [9] \n\nOption number: "))

    if unit == 1:  # meters
        height = float(input('What is the  height of the wall? '))
        width = float(input('What is the width of the wall? '))
        layers = float(input('How many layers do you want to use? '))
        area = height * width
        liters = 2 * area * layers
        print('You will need aproximately {:.2f} liters of paint.'.format(liters))

    elif unit == 2:  # centimeters
        height = float(input('What is the  height of the wall? '))
        width = float(input('What is the width of the wall? '))
        layers = float(input('How many layers do you want to use? '))
        area = (height * 0.01) * (width * 0.01)
        liters = 2 * area * layers
        print('You will need aproximately {:.2f} liters of paint.'.format(liters))

    elif unit == 3:  # inches
        height = float(input('What is the  height of the wall? '))
        width = float(input('What is the width of the wall? '))
        layers = float(input('How many layers do you want to use? '))
        area = (height * 0.0254) * (width * 0.0254)
        liters = 2 * area * layers
        print('You will need aproximately {:.2f} liters of paint.'.format(liters))

    elif unit == 9:
        break

    else:
        print('Please, answer correctly.')
```

paintcalculator()

assim você apenas chama a sua função quando deseja utilizar ela.

espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Boas, primeiramente gostaria de o informar que devia explicitar em que cenário exato ocorre o erro que refere. Dito isto, percebi que o seu problema ocorre depois do utilizador escolher uma opção no menu e não respeitar o tipo de valor inserido.

Coisas a fazer para resolver o problema e melhorar o código:

1. Cada opção do menu deveria corresponder a uma função mesmo que o código seja simples.
2. Recorrer ao mecanismo de *try* e *except* existente no python.
3. Apesar na solução apresentada não o fazer, deve ser pensada uma maneira de resolver a repetição existente em *height*, *width* e *layers*. Talvez um objeto auxiliar que guarde a informação nos seus atributos.

Aqui fica um exemplo de solução

```
def optMeters():
    height = float(input('What is the  height of the wall? '))
    width = float(input('What is the width of the wall? '))
    layers = float(input('How many layers do you want to use? '))
    area = height * width
    liters = 2 * area * layers
    print('You will need aproximately {:.2f} liters of paint.'.format(liters))


def optCentimeters():
    height = float(input('What is the  height of the wall? '))
    width = float(input('What is the width of the wall? '))
    layers = float(input('How many layers do you want to use? '))
    area = (height*0.01) * (width*0.01)
    liters = 2 * area * layers
    print(
        'You will need aproximately {:.2f} liters of paint.'.format(liters))


def optInches():
    height = float(input('What is the  height of the wall? '))
    width = float(input('What is the width of the wall? '))
    layers = float(input('How many layers do you want to use? '))
    area = (height*0.0254) * (width*0.0254)
    liters = 2 * area * layers
    print(
        'You will need aproximately {:.2f} liters of paint.'.format(liters))


def paintcalculator():
    try:
        unit = int(input(
            "What measurement unit do you use?\n1 - Meters \n2 - Centimeters \n3 - Inches \n4 - Exit \nOption number:"))
        if unit == 1:  # meters
            optMeters()

        elif unit == 2:  # centimeters
            optCentimeters()

        elif unit == 3:  # inches
            optInches()
        elif unit == 4:  # exit opt
            return
        else:
            print('Please, answer correctly.')
            paintcalculator()  # No return needed
    except:
        print('Invalid input detected')
        paintcalculator()
```

Comment: Eu tentei rodar seu código, só que o que aparece no terminal é só o local onde o arquivo está no meu pc, o que tenho que fazer? Gostei bastante do seu, me disseram pra usar a função while True, eu usei e deu cerrto, mas eu prefiro muito mais a ideia de transformar cada opção em uma função, ou classe, não sei

Comment: @LFHarada Vc pode muito bem combinar as 2 coisas: separar em funções **e** usar o `while` em vez de chamar a função dentro dela mesma...

Comment: @LFHarada o while é também uma ótima opção controlar o fluxo do código e bastaria usar um break para sair do loop, sobre o problema que descreve deve precisar de chamar a função no código (pensava que o que apresentou não era o código completo). Experimente adicionar paintcalculator() no final do código.